# Problem setting up Redux with TypeScript when having multiple action payload types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to set up redux with typescript in a react app and I don't understand what am I doing wrong. 
Here are my types and action creators.

```
export type FetchFamilyListError = {
  type: typeof FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_ERROR;
  payload: string;
};

export type FetchFamilyListSuccess = {
  type: typeof FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_SUCCESS;
  payload: Family[];
};

export type FamilyActions = FetchFamilyListError | FetchFamilyListSuccess;

export const fetchFamilyListError = (error: string): types.FamilyActions => ({
  type: types.FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_ERROR,
  payload: error
});

export const fetchFamilyListSuccess = (
  families: Family[]
): types.FamilyActions => ({
  type: types.FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_SUCCESS,
  payload: families
});
```

And here is the reducer.

```
export type familyState = {
  families: Family[];
  filters: {
    size: number;
  };
  error: string | null;
};

const initialState: familyState = {
  families: [],
  filters: {
    size: 0
  },
  error: null
};

const familyReducer = (
  state = initialState,
  action: types.FamilyActions
): familyState => {
  const actions = {
    [types.FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_ERROR]: () =>
      produce(state, draftState => {
        draftState.error = action.payload; // <--- error here
      }),
    [types.FETCH_FAMILY_LIST_SUCCESS]: () => ({
      families: [],
      filters: {
        size: 0
      },
      error: null
    }),
    default: () => state
  };
  return actions[action.type] ? actions[action.type]() : actions.default();
};
```

I'm getting **Type 'string | Family[]' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
  Type 'Family[]' is not assignable to type 'string'**
I guess this is because action.payload can either be a string or Family[], how can I fix this?

Right now I'm doing this

```
draftState.error =
          typeof action.payload === "string" ? action.payload : null;
```

But it doesn't seem like the right way to do this.

Comment: What does the `familyState` type definition look like?

Comment: Oh sorry I'll add it to the post

Comment: Hi, I'm a Redux maintainer.  I'd _strongly_ encourage you to use [our new Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which already uses Immer internally, will generate those action creators for you, and is written to provide a smooth TS experience.

Comment: @markerikson Needed to get my hands dirty before using the magic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I guess this is because action.payload can either be a string or Family[]

Correct, the issue is in your reducer, `action` is defined as `types.FamilyActions`, so when you attempt to set `draftState.error` there is ambiguity because TS can't determine which action it is dealing with.

Given we know which one it will be based on the action type, you can just cast the payload to the appropriate type e.g.

```
draftState.error = action.payload as string
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm new to TypeScript and I was looking for something like that.

Comment: @Nadhem no worries, I'm not a TS user myself but put my compiler hat on for this one :)